# WordPress Shows error 500 when W3 Total Cache Plugin is installed

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-500, w3-total-cache

When installing the W3 total cache plugin my website shows blank page. I checked the .htaccess. I also tried wp super cache plugin. This plugin also shows the same error when cache is enabled. Kindly help me to find a solution.
Thanks in advance.

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/bmp application/java application/msword application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-msdownload image/x-icon image/webp application/json application/vnd.ms-access application/vnd.ms-project application/x-font-otf application/vnd.ms-opentype application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text audio/ogg application/pdf application/vnd.ms-powerpoint image/svg+xml application/x-shockwave-flash image/tiff application/x-font-ttf application/vnd.ms-opentype audio/wav application/vnd.ms-write application/font-woff application/font-woff2 application/vnd.ms-excel
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    # DEFLATE by extension
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(bmp|class|doc|docx|eot|exe|ico|webp|json|mdb|mpp|otf|_otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|svg|svgz|swf|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|_ttf|wav|wri|woff|woff2|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|BMP|CLASS|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|ICO|WEBP|JSON|MDB|MPP|OTF|_OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|_TTF|WAV|WRI|WOFF|WOFF2|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hlbtest/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /hlbtest/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code in my dev server and did not see any errors.

That said Error 500 indicates an Internal Server Error.
If you look at your server logs (Apache and PHP), you'll be able to find the exact source. It could be anything from a parse error in PHP or an unavailable Apache module on your web host.

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can do:

1. The cache plugin could be clashing with another plugin you have installed. Try deactivating your plugins and leave the cache plugin activated. If it's working, then you have a plugin crash. Then you can slowly activate each plugin until you find the problem plugin. Remember, only use a plugin if it's absolutely necessary and it's something you can't solve in the theme development itself.
2. Try removing that blank line before # END WordPress. .htaccess files can throw errors when whitespace is detected.
3. Turn on WP_DEBUG in your wp-config file whilst developing, this can help you prevent any future errors like this.